# Deploying nodejs app using npx http-server and Nginx

Tags: nginx, node.js, pm2

I am deploying a nodejs app I have tried two alternatives but I can't understand what's the better approach in terms of performance.

The **first approach** I tried is to lunch using [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)  `npm start` (which in my case call `npx http-server ./ -p 8085 -o -c-1`).

Then using Nginx I  `proxy_pass` the port `8085` to `myexample.org/app`.

The **second approach** is to simply put the application in my root directory so that Nginx can directly serve `myexample.org/app`.

I can't understand the advantages and the disadvantages of the two approaches in both the apps seem working fine. Can you give me some reason I should opt for one approach instead of the other? Is there a better approach?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly is your second approach, as nginx can serve directly only static files.

Comment: @AlexD Thanks for you comment, I am deploying this app https://github.com/ProjectMirador/mirador if I put the content of Mirador integration test in a dir served by nginx I am able to use the app. I think nginx is serving directly the Javascript to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing serving Javascript files to the browser and serving node.js app as a backend application.

It seems that your node.js app (`npx http-server`) is an HTTP server itself and it serves your static files to the browser. You don't need to run `npx http-server` behind `nginx` if you only need to serve static files to a client browser.

But if you need to run a real node.js app then you can't just drop it into `nginx` root folder as `nginx` can serve directly only static files and you need to use something like `proxy_pass` with backend apps.

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer, I was quite confused because it seems that node was a requirement. But in this case how can I achieve load balancing for the "static applications" with pm2 I could start several server and create an upstream with nginx, with static applications what can I do?